# Initializing and remembering radio buttons

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I have read a lot of posts here and elsewhere about remembering radio buttons. I have also read a lot of posts about initialising one radio button. What I have not read a lot of is combining the two. I am wanting to do it within the input statement if possible.

Examples of remembering (ie. retaining the highlighted radio button on re-display of the page):

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" <?php echo ($sex=='Male')?'checked':'' ?   >size="17">Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" <?php echo ($sex=='Female')?'checked':'' ?> size="17">Female
```

or

```
<input type="radio" name="veg" value="cabbage" <?php if(!isset($veg)){print "     checked=\"checked\"";} if(isset($veg) && $veg == "cabbage"){print " checked=\"checked\"";} ?>> cabbage 
<input type="radio" name="veg" value="onion" <?php if(isset($veg) && $veg == "onion"){print " checked=\"checked\"";} ?>> onion
```

or

```
<input name="searchtype" type="radio" value="artist"  
<? if ($searchtype == 'artist') echo 'checked'; ?>> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
Title: 
<input name="searchtype" type="radio" value="title"  
<? if ($searchtype == 'title') echo 'checked'; ?>> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
Year: 
<input name="searchtype" type="radio" value="year"  
<? if ($searchtype == 'year') echo 'checked'; ?>>
```

The first one seems simplest, but I cannot get it to work. I keep getting some error, presumably syntax. Here is my partial code:

```
<input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact" <?php if ($_GET["typ"]=="exact") echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>Exact
<input type="radio" name="typ" value="starts" <?php if ($_GET["typ"]=="starts") echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>Starts with
<input type="radio" name="typ" value="sounds" <?php if ($_GET["typ"]=="sounds") echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>Soundex</td></tr>
<input type="submit" value="Find" /></td></tr>
```

The second issue is incorporating the default value into the above somehow.

My attempt involved using the third format of the code above and trying to test for null initially. Something like this. Once again it did not work:

Exact
    Starts with
    Soundex

The following code works, but is verbose:

```
$exact_status = 'unchecked';
$starts_status = 'unchecked';
$sounds_status = 'unchecked';

if (isset($_POST['typ'])) {
   $selected_radio = $_POST['typ'];
   if ($selected_radio == 'exact')
     {$exact_status = 'checked';} 
   else if ($selected_radio == 'starts') 
      {$starts_status = 'checked';} 
   else if ($selected_radio == 'sounds') 
      {$sounds_status = 'checked';}
}
else {
$exact_status = 'checked';} 
echo 
  '<p>Enter Surname and optionally Given Name(s):  
  <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">
  <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td valign="top">Surname:</td><td><input type="text" size=40 name="surname" value="'.$surname.'" /></td><td>Required</td></tr>
  <tr><td valign="top">Given Name(s):</td><td><input type="text" size=40 name="firstname" value="'.$firstname.'" /></td><td>Optional</td></tr>
  <tr><td valign="top">Search Type:</td><td>
    <input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact"'.$exact_status.'>Exact
    <input type="radio" name="typ" value="starts"'.$starts_status.'>Starts with
    <input type="radio" name="typ" value="sounds"'.$sounds_status.'>Soundex
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Find" /></td></tr>
  </table>
  </form>  
  <p>';
```

Based on comments below I tried this. It almost works. The first input box works. The next two just output the word "checked" instead of the input statement???

```
if (!isset($_POST['typ']))
{$radio1 = '<input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact" checked>Exact';}
else 
{$radio1 = '<input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact"'.($_GET['typ'] =="exact")?"checked":''.'>Exact';}
 $radio2 = '<input type="radio" name="typ" value="starts"'.($_GET['typ'] =="starts")?"checked":''.'>Starts with';
 $radio3 = '<input type="radio" name="typ" value="sounds"'.($_GET['typ'] =="sounds")?"checked":''.'>Soundex';

echo 
  '<p>Enter Surname and optionally Given Name(s):  
  <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">
  <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td valign="top">Surname:</td><td><input type="text" size=40 name="surname" value="'.$surname.'" /></td><td>Required</td></tr>
  <tr><td valign="top">Given Name(s):</td><td><input type="text" size=40 name="firstname" value="'.$firstname.'" /></td><td>Optional</td></tr>
  <tr><td valign="top">Search Type:</td><td>',$radio1,$radio2,$radio3, 
  '</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Find" /></td></tr>
  </table>
  </form>  
  <p>';
```

In other words after the first radio button it says: Exactcheckedchecked. The next two buttons are missing.

Comment: <input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact" <?php if ($_GET["typ"]=="exact" || $_GET["typ"]=="") echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>Exact
    <input type="radio" name="typ" value="starts" <?php if ($_GET["typ"]=="starts") echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>Starts with
    <input type="radio" name="typ" value="sounds" <?php if ($_GET["typ"]=="sounds") echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>Soundex</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Find" /></td></tr>

Comment: I also tried this for the first one:
    <input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact" <?php if ($_GET["typ"]=="exact" || !isset($typ)) echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>Exact

I also tried this one:
    <input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact" <?php if ($_GET["typ"]=="exact" || !isset($_POST['Find'])) echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>Exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact" <?php echo ($_GET['typ'] =="exact")?"checked":'' ?>>Exact
<input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact" <?php echo ($_GET['typ'] =="starts")?"checked":'' ?>>Starts with
<input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact" <?php echo ($_GET['typ'] =="sounds")?"checked":'' ?>>Soundex

<input type="submit" value="Find" /></td></tr>
```

Something like above should do the trick. It is called a shorthand if and is - I would say - only useful in above-like cases.

Please read more about it on:http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples Which has lots of examples on how to use it.

Lycka till!

Comment: no, it does not work. If I delete the php stuff it works fine. Like this.<input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact">Exact
    <input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact">Starts with
    <input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact">Soundex

Comment: How come it saves the comment as soon as I press Enter? How do I insert a new line?

Comment: I also want to cater for the initial condition. I want the first radio button to be on as default the first time through.

Comment: I should mention that all of the above is embedded as part of a PHP echo statement. Is it ok to have php embedded in the embedded stuff?

Comment: Then thats most probably the problem. You cannot echo an echo... Then first make it a string and then do it. 

I have tried the code above and it does work - syntax is ok.

Multiline comment = shift + enter.(alltough i can see it does not save as multilines. :) )

Comment: In that case I might as well just set up a variable before the initial echo I guess? Something like this: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html

Comment: Maybe someting like: `$content = '<input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact"'.($_GET['typ'] =="exact")?"checked":''.'>Exact';` This is **NOT** tested.

Comment: I got this to work to set the radio button initially:
             <input type="radio" name="typ" value="exact" <?php if (!isset($_POST['submit']) || $_REQUEST['typ'] == "exact") echo "checked"; ?>>Exact